# How to set maximum expanded height in android support design bottom sheet?

Tags: android, android-support-design

I already showed my bottom sheet layout with its peek height set to 100dp. But how can I limit my bottom sheet to expand to 500dp only? This is my sample layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/coordinator"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#e444ff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#e444ff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#e444ff" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In addition to my question, how can I disallow the user from dragging the bottom sheet up and down?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/49527832/3439133 check this in case you want to dynamically change max height

Comment: android:minHeight="100dp" 
android:maxHeight="500dp"
use both max and min. min for preventing bottom sheet from disappearing.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

to stop the bottom sheet from moving up the full screen is simple, just set a `layout_height` for your NestedScrollView to 500dp, also you probably want to set it's `layout_gravity="bottom"`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#e444ff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#e444ff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#e444ff" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

if you don't want the view to be draggable up then you need to set `behavior_peekHeight` and `layout_height` to the same values.

And to stop the view from being draggable down is the `behavior_hideable` flag  just set this to false

Comment: ow you forgot something we should set app:behavior_hideable to false so we make sure that the bottom sheet will be undraggable down

Comment: This didn't fix my bottom sheet height unfortunately. !

Comment: How To Achieve this (limiting expandable height of bottom sheet) in Modal bottom sheet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49527832/3439133, finally cracked it. Follow the link here to dynamically change the max expanded height of bottomsheet.

Answer (score 7):

You can just set param "maxHeight" to the root viewgroup of your bottom sheet.

`android:maxHeight="500dp"`

Works well with ConstraintLayout as root layout.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, does not work with nested `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [setMaxHeight](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior#setMaxHeight(int)) method from `BottomSheetBehavior` (this method should be called before `show()` method)

```
bottomSheetDialog.behavior.maxHeight = 1000 // set max height when expanded in PIXEL
bottomSheetDialog.behavior.peekHeight = 400 // set default height when collapsed in PIXEL
```

Answer (score 3):

**If using BottomSheetDialogFragment:**

In my case I was using BottomSheetDialogFragment and modified the bottom sheet peek height by getting its reference by override OnCreateDialog method inside my BottomSheetFragment

```
@NonNull @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            BottomSheetDialog bottom_dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;

            FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) bottom_dialog.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            assert bottomSheet != null;
            //BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = requireActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            int maxHeight = (int) (height*0.80);
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setPeekHeight(maxHeight);
        }
    });

    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Above solutions didn't work for me so I solved it by

**1.** added `app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"` in the root view of bottom sheet layout.

**2.** custom style for bottom sheet:

```
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet">
        <item name="behavior_peekHeight">600dp</item>
    </style>
```

**3.** And using this in Activity or Fragment by

```
    val mBottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme)
    val inflater = this.layoutInflater
    val sheetView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout, null)
    mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheetView)
    mBottomSheetDialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a constraint layout and a recyclerview inside you can use this

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_max="500dp"
app:layout_constraintHeight_min="500dp"
```

in the recyclerView.

Something like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintToptoTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="500dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="500dp"/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

For some reason, the accepted answer didn't work for me. Maybe because I'm not using a `fragment` and a `NestedScrollView` as the layout inside my `BottomSheet`. Anyway, in my case, the solution was to limit the size of the `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
<ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- Your main content here -->
   </ConstarintLayout>
   <CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="MAX SIZE OF BOTTOM SHEET">
        <YourBottomSheetLayout>
             app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   </CoordinatorLayout>
</ConstarintLayout>
```