# Open Bottom dialog from mid to top in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I want my bottom dialog open by default at mid-height and when slide, it should open to the top. Google map will be shown in the top half part and another half part will be `Bottomsheet` and when the user slides up the bottom it should open to the top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".home.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:weightSum="2"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:context=".module.ride.activity.MapsActivity"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:layout_height="0dp">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_openclose"
                       android:id="@+id/imgExpand"
                       android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Chicken Fried Rice 1x1"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Paneer Tikka 1x2"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Delivery Address"
                android:textColor="#444"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Flat No 404, Skyline Apartments, Vizag - 500576"/>

        <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="#000"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="PROCEED PAYMENT"
                android:textColor="#fff"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

My Kotlin Code

```
 var sheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*>? = null
 sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet);
        (sheetBehavior as BottomSheetBehavior<*>?)!!.setBottomSheetCallback(object :
            BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onSlide(p0: View, p1: Float) {

        }
        override fun onStateChanged(p0: View, p1: Int) {
            when (p0.id) {

                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN -> {
                    System.out.println("----------STATE_HIDDEN")
                }
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> {
                    System.out.println("-------------STATE_EXPANDED")
                }
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED -> {
                    System.out.println("-----------STATE_COLLAPSED")
                }
            }
        }
    })
    imgExpand.setOnClickListener() {
        if ((sheetBehavior as BottomSheetBehavior<*>?)!!.state != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            (sheetBehavior as BottomSheetBehavior<*>?)!!.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        } else {
            (sheetBehavior as BottomSheetBehavior<*>?)!!.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried something but it shows something like this

[image]

But I want to do something like this

[image]

Comment: You should take a look at this two library https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

https://github.com/orhanobut/dialogplus

Comment: Why are you having the bottomsheet layout in the same screen

Comment: @ManojPerumarath it should be in a different layout, it will affect  the goal.

Comment: @Mr.Patel I'm trying something similar but fail to find the issue

Comment: @Farhana i think below answer by manoj should help but still if you're facing issues i strongly suggest you to use sliding up panel layout with which you can easily implement what you want

Comment: @Mr.Patel I tried below solution and i have separated bottom view in other layout but it shows an error ` The view is not associated with BottomSheetBehavior` and i tried to resolve it but still showing.

Comment: @Farhana ok then you should go for sliding panel layout library with that you can easily do what you want tell me if you need help i'll post a demo code for that layout here

Comment: have you tried defining peek height for your bottom navigation

Comment: @VivekMishra no, can you explain it

Comment: @Farhana did you resolve this issue

Comment: @ManojPerumarath  Yes, I have combined three answers,  two below and one another have worked for me and another SO [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636671/how-to-set-maximum-expanded-height-in-android-support-design-bottom-sheet) and thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Move the attribute `app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">` from `LinearLayout` to the root view of your sheet which is `CoordinatorLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `peekHeight` for your bottomsheet should help you to get your desired behaviour. This is the definition of the peekHeight.

> **STATE_COLLAPSED**: The bottom sheet is visible but only showing its peek height. This state is usually the 'resting position' of a Bottom Sheet. The peek height is chosen by the developer and should be enough to indicate there is extra content, allow the user to trigger an action or expand the bottom sheet.